# Efficiency of quarterly calculation of workforce headcount

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have one table, per_all_peopl_f, with following columns:

```
name  person_id  emp_flag  effective_start_date   effective_end_date   DOJ
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
ABC   123          Y       30-MAR-2011              30-MAR-2013       10-FEB-2011
ABC   123          Y       24-FEB-2011              27-FEB-2011       10-FEB-2011
DEF   345          N       10-APR-2012              30-DEC-4712       15-SEP-2011
```

There are many entries (1000+) with repeated data and different effective start dates.

I have to calculate the Workforce headcount. That is, the number of employees that exits the company quarterly.

The following columns have to be fetched:

1. Headcount in 2012 (1st quarter)
2. Headcount in 2013 (1st quarter)
3. difference between the two headcounts
4. %  difference

The query I used to find the headcount quarterly is:

function1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION function_name
  (l_end_date ,l_start_date  ) 
  RETURN number;
  IS 
    l_emp

  BEGIN
    select count(distinct papf.person_id)
      into l_emp
      from per_all_people_f papf
     where papf.emp_flag ='Y'
       and effective_start_date >=l_end_date
       and effective_end_date <=l_start_date ;

    return l_emp; 
END function_name;
```

Main package:

```
create xx_pack_name  body
is 
    cursor cur_var
    is 
       select function_name('01-MAR-2012','31-MAY-2012') EMP_2012,
              function_name('01-MAR-2013','31-MAY-2013') EMP_2013,
              function_name('01-MAR-2012','31-MAY-2012')-function_name('01-MAR-2013','31-MAY-2013') Diff
         from dual;

end xx_pack_name  ;
```

Is this cost efficient?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand the question-- "cost efficient" is very subjective.  Are you asking "Are there ways to make this more efficient?"  If so, what version of Oracle are you using?  What edition?  Is result caching configured?  Is there some reason that you need to define a cursor that returns a single row with your results?  Is there a reason that you want to hard-code your dates in your package?

Comment: no i wont hard code the dates.. its just a draft code...

Comment: and by efficient  i mean better code

Comment: How are you defining the headcount for a Qtr? Is is the count at the start of the Qtr, the count at the end, the count of employess that were in a the company for any day in the quarter, something else?

Comment: I'm confused, you call your function like this `function_name(l_end_date=>'01-MAR-2012', l_start_date=>'31-MAY-2012'). Start date is greater than end date, can you please review your code?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a good variant in case if there are index on at least `effective_start_date` and `effective_end_date` fields of `per_all_people_f` table.

Ideal variant for this query is

```
create index x_per_all_people_search on per_all_people_f(   
  effective_start_date,
  effective_end_date, 
  person_id,  
  emp_flag
)
```

but it may be too expensive to maintain (disk cost, insertion speed).

Also, cursor in package body must contain subquery and reuse function call results:

```
cursor cur_var
is 
  select 
    EMP_2012,
    EMP_2013,
    (EMP_2013 - EMP_2012) Diff
  from (
   select 
     function_name('01-MAR-2012','31-MAY-2012') EMP_2012,
     function_name('01-MAR-2013','31-MAY-2013') EMP_2013
   from dual
  );
```

Of course best solution is to minimize context switches and get all values from single SQL query. Also, you can supply parameters directly to cursor:

```
cursor cur_var(
  start_1 date, end_1 date, 
  start_2 date, end_2 date
)
is 
  select 
    EMP_2012,
    EMP_2013,
    (EMP_2013 - EMP_2012) Diff
  from (
   select 
     (
       select 
         count(distinct papf.person_id)
       from 
         per_all_people_f papf
       where 
         papf.emp_flag = 'Y'
         and 
         effective_start_date >= trunc(start_1)
         and 
         effective_end_date   <= trunc(end_1)
     ) EMP_2012,
     (
       select 
         count(distinct papf.person_id)
       from 
         per_all_people_f papf
       where 
         papf.emp_flag = 'Y'
         and 
         effective_start_date >= trunc(start_2)
         and 
         effective_end_date   <= trunc(end_2)
     ) EMP_2013
   from dual
  );
```

From my point of view function/cursor parameters is too generic, may be better to create a wrapper which takes as input parameters quarter number and two years to compare.

And last, if results planned to be used in PL/SQL (I suppose that because of returning a single row) don't use cursor at all, just return calculated values through output parameters. From another point of view if you need to get quarter data for full year in one cursor it may be more efficient to count all quarters and compare it in single query.